# Regression using dummy variable

Tags: regression

I would like to regress total energy expenditure on weight and gender.  Is it better to consider gender as a dummy variable or find separate regression equations for men and women?

Comment: If you expect the error variances to be similar, one regression (with interaction, perhaps) makes more sense, since you can do things like fit parallel lines and more easily test for differences.

Answer (score 1):

Running separate regressions will get you results that are roughly equivalent to running the pooled regression with an interaction between weight and gender.  Here is an example with some made-up data

```
2> set.seed(666)
2> gender = c(rep("m",1000),rep('f',1000))
2> d = data.frame(gender)
2> d$weight = 140+rnorm(1000,sd = 30)
    2> d$energy = (as.numeric(d$gender=="f")*200)+d$weight*.5+(as.numeric(d$gender=="f")*d$weight*.05)+rgamma(1000,100,5)
2> 
2> summary(lm(energy~weight,subset(d,gender=="f")))

Call:
lm(formula = energy ~ weight, data = subset(d, gender == "f"))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.7354 -1.3408 -0.0328  1.3142  7.6783 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 2.202e+02  2.921e-01   754.1   <2e-16 ***
weight      5.483e-01  2.049e-03   267.5   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.913 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9862,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9862 
F-statistic: 7.156e+04 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

2> summary(lm(energy~weight,subset(d,gender=="m")))

Call:
lm(formula = energy ~ weight, data = subset(d, gender == "m"))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.7354 -1.3408 -0.0328  1.3142  7.6783 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 20.241637   0.292053   69.31   <2e-16 ***
weight       0.498255   0.002049  243.12   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.913 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9834,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9834 
F-statistic: 5.911e+04 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

2> summary(lm(energy~weight*gender,data=d))

Call:
lm(formula = energy ~ weight * gender, data = d)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.7354 -1.3408 -0.0328  1.3142  7.6783 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     2.202e+02  2.921e-01  754.12   <2e-16 ***
weight          5.483e-01  2.049e-03  267.51   <2e-16 ***
genderm        -2.000e+02  4.130e-01 -484.23   <2e-16 ***
weight:genderm -5.000e-02  2.898e-03  -17.25   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.913 on 1996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9997,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9997 
F-statistic: 1.995e+06 on 3 and 1996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Thank you. Which sounds better? In case I am doing separate regressions, do I have to plot the residual plots separately or one that is combined will do?

Comment: Any linear regression should have roughly normal residuals, but a lot of data/model combos won't have normal disturbances.  If you're only interested in coefficient estimates and standard errors, consider using a heteroskedasticity-consistent (aka "robust") vcv estimator.